# how to terminate data losing in laravel migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I never knew why! but one of my tables, named:`Posts` were removed when I  looked at my database in phpMyAdmin!!! so I tried to regenerating that by `php artisan migrate` but I've got this Error:

> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users'
>   already exists

My users table were exist only Posts table was removed!
this is my models:

```
class Post extends Model
{
protected $table = 'posts';
public $primaryKey = 'id';
public $timestamps = true;

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');

}
}
```

and:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public  function posts()
{

    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}

}
```

I had to use this command in user migration: `Schema::dropIfExists('users');` and ran `php artisan migrate` again. Every thing solved except all of my data in user table were dropped!

How can I terminate the same problem in laravel? how can I `disable data losing` in laravel migrations, alert me if some changescauses it to lose data.

In microsoft EF we have `EnableDataLoosing=false`; does Eloquent have same thing in laravel?

Comment: "Dropping the table" means deleting it so yes your data in that table will be lost. I would suggest either creating a data-only dump or a csv of your data then using a `Seeder` to repopulate the table after you've refreshed the migrations.

Comment: just my suggestion, backup your database before running any migration in production

Comment: What is the status of your migrations table? Once a migration has run, it shouldn't run again. If you don't want the user table creation code run - just insert it into your migrations table. It will not run.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.5 there's a new command `php artisan migrate:fresh` which will drop all your tables an rebuild them all